# Partial form in rails 3 needing different link depending on New or Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have a basic setup of views that was generated by the Rails 3 scaffolding.  It gives me a partial view **_form.html.erb**.  Both my **edit.html.erb** and my **new.html.erb** render this partial view.

In the partial view, I want to have a link_to that goes to different paths depending on if it is being rendered by the **new** or the **edit** view.

Is there an easy way to do this?

My code looks like this currently, but does not allow for different paths.

```
<%= f.submit %> or <%= link_to 'Go back', models_path %>
```

If it helps, I am trying to send them back to the page they came from (they come from different places for add and edit)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use **form.object.new_record?** instead of **params[:action]** to know if you are editing or creating (edit view versus new view).

eg:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item) do |f| %>  
    <% if @item.new_record? %>  
       <%= f.input :lost_time, input_html: { value: DateTime.now } %>  
    <% else %>                      
       <%= f.input :lost_time, input_html: { value: @item.lost_time } %>    
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nice, definitely needed this!

Comment: You can also use:  form.object.persisted? which does the same as new_record? but also checks if the object was destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

I am not that familiar with rails 3. But hope this works for you

```
<% if params[:action] == 'new' %>
    # code for new
<% elsif params[:action] == 'edit' %>
    # code for edit
<% end %>
```

GOOD LUCK :D

Comment: This is not the best solution since it won't display any link at all when validation fails and the action is create or update

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [link_to(:back)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

That might be what you need here.

Comment: This is not the best solution for security and logical reasons. "When using redirect_to :back, if there is no referrer, RedirectBackError will be raised. You may specify some fallback behavior for this case by rescuing RedirectBackError."

Comment: I later refactored and ended up passing the path as a local parameter to the form, that way if I use the form in a variety of places, I have full control.